# Why different behavior of Mathematica 12.0 and 12.1.1 on this command?

Tags: version-12, version-12.1

Why different behavior of Mathematica 12.0 and 12.1.1 on this command?

```
VectorPlot3D[{z, 1, 0}, {x, -2, 3}, {t, 0, 2}, {z, 0, 1.5},
 VectorColorFunction -> (RGBColor[0, 0.5, 0.5] &), 
 VectorColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 VectorStyle -> {Opacity[0.75], Thickness[0.006]}, 
 VectorPoints -> {8, 12, 8} , VectorScale -> {0.07, Scaled[0.6]}, 
 BoxRatios -> {2, 2, 1}, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {0, 2}, {0, 1.5}}, 
 ImageSize -> 500, ViewPoint -> {0.893, -2.825, 1.633}]
```

12.0 has no problem with this command, while 12.1.1 crashes. Both on Windows 10 64bit. 12.0 is on Dell desktop and 12.1.1 Dell laptop. I do not have both on the same computer.

Comment: It works on MMA 12.1.0 Windows 10

Comment: It also works on MMA 12.1.1 Gentoo Linux

Comment: @Daniel Huber Does it work efficiently or it lags? Can it be 12.1.1? Hard to believe!

Comment: On my PC it take 0.015 sec

Comment: Works on 12.1.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2020). Note that there are multiple "versions" of 12.1.1. Did you try updating?

Comment: @Natas That is a great idea. I will do that and report. Thank you!

Comment: If you find it still crashes your system, then you should report it to Wolfram directly.  Posting it here is not the same as filing a bug report.

Comment: Works on 12.1.1 (June 19, 2020) for Windows 10 64bit Home(1809 version) on Lenovo  laptop. :)

Comment: Works promptly on "12.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)"

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because no one can reproduce the problem the OP is experiencing

Comment: Thank you all! I just reinstalled v12.1.1 with no improvement. :-(

Comment: Try deleting the contents (except for the licence file) in your `$UserBaseDirectory`. That often helps get rid of inexplicable bugs. Just evaluate `SystemOpen[$UserBaseDirectory]` to find it quickly.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Thank you for your suggestion. I tried, unfortunately, it did not help! I reported the problem to Wolfram Support.